# Creating multiple python dictionaries from a file

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

So I have no idea where to begin here but I need to take the information from a file similar to http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/iris/iris.data and have the program run a function that will return 3 new dictionaries based on type. In this file there are 3 flower types so I need to have the program read the file and take the measurements and put them in dictionaries for the type of flower. (I hope I am being clear). From there I have a lot that I will have these dictionaries do for other functions but I know how to do that just not sure how to sort this file into the three dictionaries. I am using Python 2.7. Thanks all.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.  
StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial service.

Comment: Basically, we expect you to *try* to write the code yourself.  So far, you haven't even attempted to read lines from the file.  Give it your best shot, then post the code here, and we'll help you over whatever *specific programming problem* you have.

Comment: also, you will find the `csv` module helpful

Comment: infile = open('Iris.txt','r')
def getData():
    d = {}
    for line in infile:
        info = line.strip().split()
        name = info[0]
        measurments = float(info[1])
        d[name] = measurments
    print d

Answer (score 0):

Read the file line by line. Split each line on ','. Have a dictionary with key as flower type and list of measurements being value. Each time, you get new measurements for the type append to the list.

Comment: I'll post my little bit of code here but the issue I am running into is that I have added all info to a .txt file and the program wont even open it. I just have the file saved to my desktop and I dont know anything here so do I need to upload the file a certain way and is my code sufficient otherwise. I literally dont know anything and need help.                                                                                                          Code is as follows:

Comment: [code]infile = open('Iris.txt','r')
def getData():
    d = {}
    for line in infile:
        info = line.strip().split()
        name = info[0]
        measurments = float(info[1])
        d[name] = measurments
    print d[code]